2013 Workflow to Send Reminder Email Based on Date, but Not if Date Entered in Other Column
I am trying to set up a 2013 list workflow in Designer to send an email 24hrs from a certain date and time. The catch here is that we have a column called "Date Closed" with the data type set as a date only, that is blank until the task is closed out, and if there's a date entered in there, I do NOT want the email to send. Here is the workflow as it's set up now (note: 'Suspense' is what we call the deadline date/time):

If ThisItem:Suspense is greater than Today


Add 0 months, -1 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes to to CurrentItem:Suspense (Output to Variable: date)


Then Log Variable: date to workflow history list


Then Pause until Variable: date


then Email redacted@redacted.com


End of workflow

The above workflow does email exactly 24 hours from the date and time set. However, there are items in the list that we will update with a "Date Closed" before 24hrs from the deadline, and at that point, we no longer need the notification.
I tried a couple of things such as adding a stage before saying "If ThisItem: Date Closed is less than or equal to Today" then Log to workflow history list and go to end of workflow, but I don't know how to set an action to bypass the above workflow if there's something in "Date Closed" field.
Very basically: I want an email ONLY if something is exactly 24 hours from right now, and is not yet closed out. At no other time do I want an email sent. What am I doing wrong?
